# AJAX ASP .NET Accordion Button Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, accordion

I have an accordion dynamically creating entries based on databind() record count.
I am trying to attach a handler and call an action in C# code behind when they click a button. 
I need to delete by the ID stored in the PersonId hidden field.
Here is the definition of the accordion:

```
    <asp:Accordion ID="PersonAccordion" runat="server"
        >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="PersonId" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnPersonDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete Person"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="PersonDetails" runat="server">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col c1-2">
                            <label class="txt-right c1-2">Name</label>
                            <div class="input-txt">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:Accordion>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
    int group = Convert.ToInt32(Session["group"]);

    //get list of current drivers
    Persons[] persons= Person.Search(group );

    PersonAccordion.DataSource = persons;
    PersonAccordion.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a way to select the person that you want to delete.  Probably the best way to do this is to have a Javascript script in your html that applies a style class to the name that is clicked, and applies a different class to the rest of the items in the accordion.  At the same time, this script can put the id of the clicked item in the hidden person id field.  In the template for the accordion items, you would put this script as the handler for the click event on the item.